# Google-chat: Open dialog on Button Click

Tags: google-chat, google-chat-api

I post simple message with cards_v2. I placed a Button with properties:

```
action: {
  function = "myAction",
  interaction = "OPEN_DIALOG"
}
```

When I click on button I receive event but no DialogEventType is provided.
I tried to reply with Dialog payload, but Google says bad response.

I used this: https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/dialogs?hl=en#apps-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog buttons works only if I send a response on message. When I posted cards through API POST it doesn't work.

I can't say is this a bug of Feature.